# Update a record using apache nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

What I am trying to do is exactly same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53876754/replace-string-value-to-integer-value-in-nifi-within-a-same-column/)

But when I use `QueryRecord` processor I get an error :

> Error while preparing statement.

In my scenario, I have 60+ columns and I want to perform this only on the 59th column.

SQL statement :

```
select ... (many columns),
case when MSISDN=1994 then 0
when MSISDN=94 then 0
end MSISDN,
..(another a few columns)
from Flowfile
```

I just want to replace 1994 or 94 with 0.

Do I have to use another processor for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message states

> Error while preparing statement.

your SQL query is invalid.

Input:

```
ID,MSISDN,FOO
1,1994,X
2,94,Y
```

Query:

```
SELECT ID,
    CASE 
        WHEN MSISDN=1994 THEN 0
        WHEN MSISDN=94 THEN 1
    END MSISDN,
    CASE 
        WHEN FOO='X' THEN 'BAR'
        WHEN FOO='Y' THEN 'BAZ'
    END FOO
FROM Flowfile
```

Output:

[image]

Flow:

[image]

QueryRecord properties:

[image]

PS: if you still can't create a valid query, add the full query to your question, so we can figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Problem is that I have more than 70 columns in this csv with multimillion records. I did this using `UpdateRecord` processor, it solved my problem. I will accept this as the answer as it may help someone in future.